# How to create trie-tree like data structure via doublets

Tags: c#, database, links-platform

Maybe someone has already used this engine
https://github.com/linksplatform/Data.Doublets

I try to store data, but don't know how to implement such things

```cs
// declaring links
.....
var root = links.Create();
links.Update(root, root, root);
// (root : root->root)


var h_node = links.CreatePoint();
var s_node = links.CreatePoint();

// i want:
// (root->h)
// (root->s)
root = links.Update(root, root, h_node);
root = links.Update(root, root, s_node);
    .....
```

I can create **(root : root->h)** but...
How to implement links as in this picture: [image]

I sell that a doublet cannot have more than one target.

That is, root has a links to the set
**(root : root->(h, s))**

I can only assume this solution (**but it is different**)

```
(root : root->root)
(h : h->root)
(s : s->root)
......
```

[image: i assume]

I want

```
(root : root->root
    root->h
    root->s
)
```

[image: i want]

`for experiments`
https://dotnetfiddle.net/GgYPKU

Answer (score 2):

Though it is possible to replicate the picture exactly using this style of structure template:

```
(h : h -> h)
(root : root -> root)
(node : node -> node)
(link : root -> node)
(typedLink : h -> link)
```

for

[image]

A less number of links can be used:

[image: trie as links]

```
(root : root -> root)

(h : h -> h)
(e : e -> e)
(r : r -> r)
(s : s -> s)
(i : i -> i)

(1 : 1 -> 1)
(2 : 2 -> 2)
(3 : 3 -> 3)
(4 : 4 -> 4)

(root_h_link : root -> h)
(root_h_e_link : root_h_link -> e)
(root_h_e_1_link : root_h_e_link -> 1)
(root_h_e_r_link : root_h_e_link -> r)
(root_h_e_r_s_link : root_h_e_r_link -> s)
(root_h_e_r_s_4_link : root_h_e_r_s_link -> 4)
(root_h_i_link : root_h_link -> i)
(root_h_i_s_link : root_h_i_link -> s)
(root_h_i_s_3_link : root_h_i_s_link -> 3)
(root_s_link : root -> s)
(root_s_h_link : root_s_link -> h)
(root_s_h_e_link : root_s_h_link -> e)
(root_s_h_e_2_link : root_s_h_e_link -> 2)
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Platform.Data;
using Platform.Data.Doublets;
using Platform.Data.Doublets.Memory.United.Generic;

// A doublet links store is mapped to "db.links" file:
using var links = new UnitedMemoryLinks<uint>("db.links");

// nodes

var root = links.CreatePoint();

var h_node = links.CreatePoint();

var e_node = links.CreatePoint();
var r_node = links.CreatePoint();

var s_node = links.CreatePoint();

var i_node = links.CreatePoint();

var node_1 = links.CreatePoint();
var node_2 = links.CreatePoint();
var node_3 = links.CreatePoint();
var node_4 = links.CreatePoint();

// links

var root_h_link = links.CreateAndUpdate(root, h_node);
var root_h_e_link = links.CreateAndUpdate(root_h_link, e_node);
var root_h_e_1_link = links.CreateAndUpdate(root_h_e_link, node_1);
var root_h_e_r_link = links.CreateAndUpdate(root_h_e_link, r_node);
var root_h_e_r_s_link = links.CreateAndUpdate(root_h_e_r_link, s_node);
var root_h_e_r_s_4_link = links.CreateAndUpdate(root_h_e_r_s_link, node_4);
var root_h_i_link = links.CreateAndUpdate(root_h_link, i_node);
var root_h_i_s_link = links.CreateAndUpdate(root_h_i_link, s_node);
var root_h_i_s_3_link = links.CreateAndUpdate(root_h_i_s_link, node_3);
var root_s_link = links.CreateAndUpdate(root, s_node);
var root_s_h_link = links.CreateAndUpdate(root_s_link, h_node);
var root_s_h_e_link = links.CreateAndUpdate(root_s_h_link, e_node);
var root_s_h_e_2_link = links.CreateAndUpdate(root_s_h_e_link, node_2);

// result output

Func<string, string> replaceAddressesToNames = (sourceString) => {
    sourceString = Regex.Replace(sourceString, $@"\b{root}\b", "'root'");
    sourceString = Regex.Replace(sourceString, $@"\b{h_node}\b", "'h'");
    sourceString = Regex.Replace(sourceString, $@"\b{e_node}\b", "'e'");
    sourceString = Regex.Replace(sourceString, $@"\b{r_node}\b", "'r'");
    sourceString = Regex.Replace(sourceString, $@"\b{s_node}\b", "'s'");
    sourceString = Regex.Replace(sourceString, $@"\b{i_node}\b", "'i'");
    sourceString = Regex.Replace(sourceString, $@"\b{node_1}\b", "'1'");
    sourceString = Regex.Replace(sourceString, $@"\b{node_2}\b", "'2'");
    sourceString = Regex.Replace(sourceString, $@"\b{node_3}\b", "'3'");
    sourceString = Regex.Replace(sourceString, $@"\b{node_4}\b", "'4'");
    return sourceString;
};

void printChildren(IList<uint> link, int offset) {
    var constants = links.Constants;
    links.Each((innerLink) => {
        if (links.GetIndex(innerLink) == links.GetIndex(link)) {
            return constants.Continue;
        }
        Console.Write(new string('\t', offset));
        Console.WriteLine(replaceAddressesToNames(links.Format(innerLink)));
        printChildren(innerLink, offset + 1);
        return constants.Continue;
    }, new uint[] { constants.Any, links.GetIndex(link), constants.Any });
};

Console.WriteLine(replaceAddressesToNames(links.Format(root)));
printChildren(links.GetLink(root), 1);
```

Expected output:

```
('root': 'root' 'root')
    (11: 'root' 'h')
        (12: 11 'e')
            (14: 12 'r')
                (15: 14 's')
                    (16: 15 '4')
            (13: 12 '1')
        (17: 11 'i')
            (18: 17 's')
                (19: 18 '3')
    (20: 'root' 's')
        (21: 20 'h')
            (22: 21 'e')
                (23: 22 '2')
```

[Execute at .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OSgxo1).

Comment: Ok. Thanks.
But how can I use a tree search without recursion and Each method for all links?

Comment: @uselessgoddess what kind of search do you want to perform on that tree?

Comment: for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#:~:text=algorithms,-%5Bedit